# Bootstrap simple carousel: how to display it on front-end?

Tags: 8

I've installed [Bootstrap simple carousel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_simple_carousel) and I know how to add/edit slides. But I didn't find anywhere instructions on how to display them on the front-end. Module didn't create any new block, view or something?!?

How to display slide show on the front-end?

Comment: @Jdrupal I do see back-end pages. Under "Structure" there is "Bootstrap simple carousel items" and I can add images there. I just don't see any block or any other way to display it on front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at https://git.drupalcode.org/project/bootstrap_simple_carousel/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/Block/CarouselBlock.php

> ```
> /**
>  * Provides a 'Bootstrap simple carousel' Block.
>  *
>  * @Block(
>  *   id = "bootstrap_simple_carousel_block",
>  *   admin_label = @Translation("Bootstrap simple carousel block")
>  * )
>  */
> ```

There is a block for it, called, "Bootstrap simple carousel block". You just have to place it in a region over at /admin/structure/block

Comment: I saw somewhere that this block should exist, but I just don't see it on my blocks admin page?

Comment: @MilanG did you search for it after clicking the "place block" button? (located on the left, beside the region name)

Comment: Ah, you are right!, It's there. Any idea how to embed this block from some template file?

Comment: @MilanG install [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak). You can then print it with `{{ drupal_block('bootstrap_simple_carousel_block') }}`, see [cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet)